# SOLR Facet Search- Facet count changes

Tags: solr

In Solr I have to fetch list of all available brands on selecting a category.

I have set `fq=brand%3A"Flipkart"` and in facets I set `facet=true&facet.field=brand`.

Initially when `fq` is not set for all brands i have some count value but when i apply brand as "Flipkart" the counts of other brands go down to zero. How can I still retrieve those initial counts of all brands? Result produced is as expected but count of brand goes down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about to filter by a facet-value. A filter which does only restrict the resultlist and but does not restrict the corresponding facet field.

What you are looking for are [tagged filter queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-TaggingandExcludingFilters):

```
q=my+main+query&fq={!tag=brandTag}brand%3A"Flipkart"&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=brandTag}brand
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This is exactly what i wanted :)